# Mocking MongoCollection crashes - Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, mongodb, nunit, moq, mongodb-.net-driver

I use Moq to mock the `GetCollection` method but the line crashes.

```
var collectionSettings = new MongoCollectionSettings
{
    GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard,
    ReadEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(),
    ReadPreference = new ReadPreference(),
    WriteConcern = new WriteConcern(),
    WriteEncoding = new UTF8Encoding()
};

var collection = new Mock<MongoCollection<BsonDocument>>(database.Object, "MyCollection", collectionSettings);

//crashing here without any error dumped
database.Setup(f => f.GetCollection("MyCollection", collectionSettings)).Returns(collection.Object);
```

This is the error I got

```
Exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' was thrown.
Parameter name: name
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxyInstance(Type proxyType, List`1 proxyArguments, Type classToProxy, Object[] constructorArguments)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
   at Moq.Proxy.CastleProxyFactory.CreateProxy(Type mockType, ICallInterceptor interceptor, Type[] interfaces, Object[] arguments)
   at Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__0()
   at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke(Action action)
   at Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance()
   at Moq.Mock`1.OnGetObject()
   at Moq.Mock.GetObject()
   at Moq.Mock.get_Object()
   at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object()
```

Any idea about hot to fix it?

Comment: If you use a try/catch, are you able to catch any errors? Typically, that kind of failure usually signifies that `GetCollection` is not overridable.

Comment: @Tejs Oh yeah. Thx! This is the error `{"Exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' was thrown.\r\nParameter name: name"}`

Comment: That certainly sounds like `GetCollection`, the actual method definition, is being run, or something that it calls. I suspect your Mock is not sufficient.

Comment: @Tejs Thx! I will take a deeper look at what I missed. This is pain in the ass...

Comment: Based on the additional error details you have posted, the error comes in the constructor for `MongoCollection<BsonDocument>`. Check your parameters to the Mock constructor, since the original's constructor is going to be called when making the `Mock<>` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the source code, I figured out I missed some properties or methods to mock.

Here is the working code:

```
public MongoServer GetMockedMongoDbServer()
{
    var serverSettings = new MongoServerSettings
    {
        Servers = new List<MongoServerAddress>
        {
            new MongoServerAddress("unittest")
        }
    };
    var server = new MongoServer(serverSettings);
    return server;
}

public static Mock<MongoCollection<T>> CreateMockCollection<T>(MongoDatabase database, string name)
{
    var collectionSetting = new MongoCollectionSettings();
    var m = new Mock<MongoCollection<T>>(database, name, collectionSetting);
    m.Setup(x => x.Database).Returns(database);
    m.Setup(x => x.Settings).Returns(collectionSetting);
    return m;
}

public MongoDatabase GetMockedMongoDb(MongoServer server)
{
    var databaseSettings = new MongoDatabaseSettings()
    {
        GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard,
        ReadEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(),
        ReadPreference = new ReadPreference(),
        WriteConcern = new WriteConcern(),
        WriteEncoding = new UTF8Encoding()
    };

    var database = new Mock<MongoDatabase>(server, "db_name", databaseSettings);

    var message = String.Empty;

    //need to mock the following stuff
    database.Setup(db => db.Settings).Returns(databaseSettings);
    database.Setup(db => db.IsCollectionNameValid(It.IsAny<string>(), out message)).Returns(true);

    //mock the collection
    var c = CreateMockCollection(database.Object, "MyCollectionName");
    database.Setup(f => f.GetCollection("MyCollectionName")).Returns(c.Object);

    return database.Object;
}

public IMongoDbContext GetMockedMongoContext()
{
    var server = GetMockedMongoDbServer();
    var database = GetMockedMongoDb(server);

    var mongoDbContext = new Mock<IMongoDbContext>();
    mongoDbContext.Setup(x => x.GetMongoDatabase()).Returns(database);

    return mongoDbContext.Object;
}
```

Comment: Could you please help me on this where `GetMongoDatabase()` comes from on line => `mongoDbContext.Setup(x => x.GetMongoDatabase()).Returns(database);`?

Comment: @er-sho LOL! It's been 5.5 years and I have no idea about mongodb or mangodb any more! And I have no idea what I was trying to solve. I seemed to be a genius then but now I can't remember anything. Sorry :)

Comment: No problem. I'll try to find another ways. But if you found or remember then please let me know upon same. Thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer doesn't work for C# driver version 1.9.1 and uses some undisclosed types introduced by OP. I have altered the helper methods that allow for mocking a `MongoCollection<T>`:

```
public static class MongoMock
{
    public static Mock<MongoServer> CreateMongoServer()
    {
        var serverSettings = new MongoServerSettings
        {
            Servers = new List<MongoServerAddress>
            {
                new MongoServerAddress("MockServer")
            }
        };

        var server = new Mock<MongoServer>(MockBehavior.Strict, serverSettings);

        string message;
        server.Setup(s => s.Settings).Returns(serverSettings);
        server.Setup(s => s.IsDatabaseNameValid(It.IsAny<string>(), out message)).Returns(true);

        return server;
    }

    public static Mock<MongoDatabase> CreateMongoDatabase(MongoServer server)
    {
        var databaseSettings = new MongoDatabaseSettings
        {
            GuidRepresentation = GuidRepresentation.Standard,
            ReadEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(),
            ReadPreference = new ReadPreference(),
            WriteConcern = new WriteConcern(),
            WriteEncoding = new UTF8Encoding()
        };
        var database = new Mock<MongoDatabase>(MockBehavior.Strict, server, "MockDatabase", databaseSettings);

        string message;
        database.Setup(db => db.Server).Returns(server);
        database.Setup(db => db.Settings).Returns(databaseSettings);
        database.Setup(db => db.IsCollectionNameValid(It.IsAny<string>(), out message)).Returns(true);

        return database;
    }

    public static Mock<MongoCollection<T>> CreateMongoCollection<T>(MongoDatabase database, string collectionName)
    {
        var collectionSetting = new MongoCollectionSettings();
        var collectionMock = new Mock<MongoCollection<T>>(MockBehavior.Strict, database, collectionName, collectionSetting);
        collectionMock.Setup(x => x.Database).Returns(database);
        collectionMock.Setup(x => x.Settings).Returns(collectionSetting);
        return collectionMock;
    }

    public static Mock<MongoCollection<T>> CreateMongoCollection<T>(string collectionName)
    {
        var server = CreateMongoServer().Object;
        var database = CreateMongoDatabase(server);
        return CreateMongoCollection<T>(database.Object, collectionName);
    }

    public static Mock<MongoCursor<T>> CreateMongoCursor<T>(MongoCollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items = null)
    {
        var cursorMock = new Mock<MongoCursor<T>>(MockBehavior.Strict, collection, null, null, null, null);

        if (items != null)
        {
            cursorMock.Setup(c => c.GetEnumerator()).Returns(items.GetEnumerator());
        }

        return cursorMock;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var serverMock = MongoMock.CreateMongoServer();
var server = serverMock.Object;

var databaseMock = MongoMock.CreateMongoDatabase(serverMock.Object);
var database = databaseMock.Object;

var collectionMock = MongoMock.CreateMongoCollection<BsonDocument>(databaseMock.Object, "FooCollection");
var collection = collectionMock.Object;

var cursorMock = MongoMock.CreateMongoCursor(collectionMock.Object, new List<BsonDocument>());
var cursor = cursorMock.Object;
```

Comment: How you will add mock collection data?

Comment: @Usama by setting up `Find()` on the `collectionMock` to return a cursor (create through `MongoMock.CreateMongoCursor()`), where you can provide an `IEnumerable<T>` that will be returned to the code calling `Find()`.

Comment: can you share that code this fully working mock on gist or here?